# Moving a group of sprites as one

Tags: pygame, sprite, game-physics

I am working with Python 2.7 and pygame on a space invaders clone. I can get my tank to move, fire bullets and the alien ships are deleted so the collision detection is working fine. I have created a sprite group and I was hoping that I could move all the ships as one using this group. 
I also tried the "unionall" but this doesn't seem to work with the group. 
I can loop through all the ships like this:

```
shipXpos = []
for ship in shipList:
    shipXpos.append(ship.rect.x)
```

Then,

```
shipXMax = max(shipXpos)
shipXMin = min(shipXpos)
```

In this way I want to find the boundary of the ships (although I guess rect.right and rect.left would be better) compared to the edges if the screen so that I can change the ship direction.

It seems if I could treat all the sprites as one big rect that would be the easiest way.

I hope this makes sense and is clear. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm the description for the "movement" tag says "DO NOT USE - ambiguous"... are you sure you want to use it? It may be ambiguous, imo :)

Answer (score 1):

In the Sprite class for the alien ships, write an `update` function that moves the alien ship. You can pass it any parameters you might need (such as current direction left or right). Then, use `pygame.sprite.Group.update()` in your main program to update all the Sprites at once.

Depending on your desired behavior, you might not need to check the sides of the screen for collision. I assume you want to move all alien ships in unison, meaning if the outermost hits the edge, you want all the ships to change direction. The original space invaders does this even if the outermost ship has been destroyed, meaning the remaining ships will not move to the outer edge, but stay on their predefined path. In that case every ship moves a set number of pixels to the right before changing to the left and you just need to keep track of that loop in the `update` function.

Comment: That makes sense thank you. I actually managed to do it in a slightly different way in the meantime. I wrote a function to find the max and min x positions of all the ships. So I passed the current ships list into the function and returned the max and min positions. These, coupled with the ship direction were then fed into an if statement that decides the next move based upon the current position. Thanks for that and also I didn't know that original game did that. Great answer thank you again.